# custom parser for digits and characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

Hi I would like to write a parser like the one below except I would like it to take characters with the the digits like `345j`, `982p0`. What would I change to be able to have characters with numbers?

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "digit",
    is: function (s, table) {
        var c = table.config;
        return $.tablesorter.isDigit(s, c);
    },
    format: function (s) {
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s);
    },
    type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: Do you want "bobjones" to be valid? What about "bobj0nes"?

Comment: Please edit your question and put your source in a code block. Highlight the source code, then hit ctrl-shift-k, or click the matched braces button `{ }`

Comment: Also, do you specifically want to allow any combination of numbers and letters? What about punctuation or spaces?

Comment: @Alex: It's just ctrl-k.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to allow any combination of letters and/or numbers, but nothing else, you could use a regular expression:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "alphanumeric",
    is: function(s, table) {
        return /^[a-z0-9]*$/i.test(s);
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return s;
    },
    type: "text"
});
```

The regular expression is `/^[a-z0-9]*$/i`, which matches any combination of only `a-z` and `0-9`, case-insensitive. I changed your format function as well, since you can't parse this as a float, and change the name and type to reflect the changes in the parser.